# com.google Redirects to Google

Tags: google-chrome, dns, tld

I noticed this little quirk the other day and was wondering how it was possible as the .google TLD is not real. Even Google itself does not sell it through its own domain service. Unless they can have their own private TLD just for kicks, I don't see how this is possible. Perhaps its a DNS thing... I'm not really sure at this point as the internet never seizes to amaze me. I haven't tried this in other browsers, so it may just be a chrome thing. Any who, an answer would be appreciated though its not imperative.

Best Regards,
Emanuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.google is actually a real TLD, apparently google requested it recently.

More info here:

http://googleblog.blogspot.com.ar/2012/05/expanding-internet-domain-space.html

http://icannwiki.com/.google